# Why does the printer keep disappearing?

Tags: windows-xp, printer, event-viewer

My neighbour has an Epson SX130.  All has been fine for a long time, until recently when the printer has regularly started to disappear from his XP machine and is not visible in the printers control panel.  When he re-installs the drivers all is fine for a day, or a week, or in the latest case a month before it disappears again.

I have installed the latest driver from Epson's website, but this hasn't improved the situation.

Each time, the windows system event log shows 2 records :

> Printer EPSON SX130 Series is pending deletion.

and then 6 seconds later

> Printer EPSON SX130 Series was deleted.

Both are attributed to his user logon rather than SYSTEM.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Oddly, I've seen the same odd symptom on a Mac with a Brother printer.

Comment: How is the computer connecting to the printer? USB, LPT or Wireless?

Comment: Is your windows patching up-to-date?  Has you system been compromised?

Comment: Hi Thanks for this.  The printer is connected by USB. It is set to auto install windows updates and they all appear to be ok and up to date. As to whether the system is comprimised or not, I'm assuming not - there are no other obvious signs of infection, it is behaving itself other than this and the virus checker is up to date on updates - though obviously, this isn't  aguarantee that it is infection free.